# Incorrect legend titles format in Core plot pieChart

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using this to show legend titles:

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"titles: %@", list[index]);
    return list[index];
}
```

I can see console output:

```
titles: Entertaiment
titles: Entertaiment
titles: Entertaiment
titles: Entertaiment

.
.
.
```

But on the iPhone I'm seeing this:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

`(CorePlot_1.5.1 Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.1)`

**Edit:**

My configureLegend method look like this. I add legend to scrollView

```
-(void)configureLegend {

    // 1 - Get graph instance
    graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

    // 2 - Create legend
    CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];

    // 2 - Set up text style

    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Thin";
    textStyle.fontSize = 15.0f;

    [[graph legend] setTextStyle:(CPTTextStyle *)textStyle];

    theLegend.numberOfColumns = 2;
    theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = nil;
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    theLegend.hidden = NO;

    // 4 - Add legend to graph
    graph.legend = theLegend;
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;

    CGFloat legendPadding = 1.0;
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding, 0.0);


    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 0, _secondView.frame.size.width, _secondView.frame.size.height + 20)];


    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_secondView.frame.size.width + 100, _secondView.frame.size.height + 400); //(scrollView.contentSize.width, 1000)

    for (UIView *subView in self.secondView.subviews)
    {
         [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [scrollView.layer addSublayer:self.hostView.hostedGraph.legend];
    [self.secondView addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO; 
}
```

Comment: There indeed seems to be an error. In CorePlot, they use to draw, then "reverse plot the view" correctly. Do you call manually the legend view?

Comment: I add legend to another view. Updated the question

Comment: So try this: `[[yourTitleView layer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1, 0, 0)];`

Answer (score 0):

Since you add manually the legend view, you have this "reversed view issue".
Indeed, they draw the plots on a "reversed view", and they do the reverse. If I remember well, they do this because of the coordinates (x,y) to make it more understandable, since (x=0,y=0) should be at the left corner up, which is not how you usually do your graph.
So the solution, is to reverse it:

```
[[yourTitleView layer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1, 0, 0)];
```